# Acessing Sharepoint sites content using graph api

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to download some video content from my organization SharePoint. I have followed the below steps.

1. Got bearer token by making a post call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token.
2. Then i am able to access graphapi using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites.

I want to know how can i reach my video content after that and how can i download it or play it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to [Download the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the content of the file stored in Sharepoint.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

The response will contain a pre-authenticated download URL for the file. Just use this url to download it.

Comment: On sending this request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/items i am getting "message": "The provided drive id appears to be malformed, or does not represent a valid drive.",

Comment: @NayanSharma You should call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives` to list the drives id first. And then use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items`.